# Yet another bibliography style question

Tags: biblatex

(I hope my question is not duplicated)

I have this sample file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Sezione}
Questo è un test.\nocite{Zarlino1558}   

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My bibliografia.bib contains:

```
@Book{Zarlino1558,
  Title                    = {L'istitutioni harmoniche},
  Author                   = {Zarlino, Gioseffo},
  Publisher                = {Francesco de' Franceschi},
  Year                     = {1558},
  Address                  = {Venezia},
}
```

I get this:

[1] Gioseffo Zarlino. *L’istitutioni harmoniche*. Venezia: Francesco de’ Franceschi, 1558.

I need this:

\textsc{Gioseffo Zarlino}, \textit{L’istitutioni harmoniche}, Venezia, Francesco de’ Franceschi, 1558.

What should I write in my preamble?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm confused. You have `polyglossia` in your preamble, which is incompatible with `pdflatex` but `fontenc` and `inputenc` which should not be used with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Which tex-engine are you using?

Comment: Sorry, just forget fontenc and inputec, I'm using XeLaTex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, with the `xpatch` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliografia.bib}
@Book{Zarlino1558,
Title = {L'istitutioni harmoniche},
Author = {Zarlino, Gioseffo},
Publisher = {Francesco de' Franceschi},
Year = {1558},
Address = {Venezia},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\let\mkbibnamelast\textsc%
\let\mkbibnamefirst\textsc%
\let\mkbibnameprefix\textsc%
\let\mkbibnameaffix\textsc
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\xpatchbibmacro{publisher+location+date}{\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}{}{}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Sezione}
Questo è un test.\nocite{Zarlino1558}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. How do you get rid of [1] at the beginning of the line?

Comment: Oh! I didnt notice you want no number at the beginning of the line. Just use the `authortitle` style. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Now I just need to order my bibliography first by Author name, then by year.

Comment: That is set by the `sorting=nyt` key  (`name-year-title`). I've updated the code.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

- You need to set `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\textit{#1}}` to make the title italic.

If you just want to change the appearance of a `book`, you can use 
`\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\textit{#1}}`.

- For commas between the keys you need to add `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}`.
- For authors in small caps, renew the bibcommands `mkbibnamelast` and `mkbibnamefirst`
  `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}}`

Complete Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}


\begin{filecontents*}{bibliografia.bib}
@Book{Zarlino1558,
  Title                    = {L'istitutioni harmoniche},
  Author                   = {Zarlino, Gioseffo},
  Publisher                = {Francesco de' Franceschi},
  Year                     = {1558},
  Address                  = {Venezia},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\textit{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Sezione}
Questo è un test.\nocite{Zarlino1558}   

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is good, except that I need commas between Author and Title, Title and Address, Address and Publisher, Publisher and year. I also need to cancel the field [1].

Comment: Also the Author doesn't get printed in SmallCaps.

Comment: I added Code for the commas, I will check on the authors.

Comment: I still get a colon between address and publisher. Is there soemthing similar to \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} for changing colon to comma?