# Smallcaps and Ubuntu 16 update

Tags: biblatex, small-caps

The following solution, provided here: [Yet another bibliography style question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271283/yet-another-bibliography-style-question) does not work anymore. Only the DI part of the author name appears in smallcaps (while it needs to be all in smallcaps).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@Book{Aristosseno,
  Title = {Armonikon Stoikeion},
  Author = {Aristosseno di Taranto},
  Keywords = {antico}
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\let\mkbibnamelast\textsc%
\let\mkbibnamefirst\textsc%
\let\mkbibnameprefix\textsc%
\let\mkbibnameaffix\textsc
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\xpatchbibmacro{publisher+location+date}{\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}{}{}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Sezione}
This is a test.\nocite{Aristosseno}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

It happened after updating to Ubuntu 16: a bug uninstalled biber, which had to be reinstalled from source.

Any help or any workaround suggestion?
Thank you,

Comment: Update of biblatex a while ago, maybe @moewe can amend the linked answer.

Comment: See [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864). You will need to replace `\mkbibnamelast` by `\mkbibnamefamily`; `\mkbibnamefirst` by `\mkbibnamegiven`; `\mkbibnameaffix` by `\makebibnamesuffix` in your code above.